# Trouble with toggleClass() for dynamically generated elements from Ajax .each()

Tags: jquery, ajax, each, slidetoggle, toggleclass

On a successful `.ajax()` call, I'm creating a set of `div`'s with forecasted weather data.  I want to only show the `div` with `class="forecast-list"` initially, and listen for the user's click on the element to show the additional data from the `<div class="box hide">`

JS to to create DIVs:

```
 //HTML to append to document
                var html =
                    '<div class="forecast-list"><ul class="list">' +
                    '<li class="item" id="day">' + forecastDay + '</li>' +
                    '<li class="item"><canvas class="' + forecastIcon + '" width="40" height="40"></canvas></li>' +
                    '<li class="item forecastTemp" id="max">' + forecastMax + '</li>' +
                    '<li class="item forecastTemp" id="min">' + forecastMin + '</li>' +
                    '<li class="item"><span class="btn">+</span></li>' +
                    '</ul></div>' +

                    //The following div is hidden when the DOM loads
                    '<div class="box hide"><ul>' +
                    '<li>SUNRISE: ' + sunriseTime + '</li>' +
                    '<li>SUNSET: ' + sunsetTime + '</li>' +
                    '<div class="box-second-line">' +
                    '<li>LOW: ' + forecastMin + ' @' + minTempTime + '</li>' +
                    '<li>HIGH: ' + forecastMax + ' @' + maxTempTime + '</li>' +
                    '</ul></div></div><br><br>';

                //Append HTML to document
                $('.forecast').append(html);
```

I've hidden the second `div` when the DOM loads and have my click handler set as...

```
//Click event to unhide hidden forecast data
            $(document).on('click', '.forecast-list', function () {
                $(this).next($('.box')).toggleClass('hide', false);  
            });
```

On click, the hidden `div` shows, but on second click nothing happens.  The effect I'm looking for is that when you click on a certain day's forecast, the data for that day with expand down into it's own `div`.  If there is another `div` open with the extra information from another day, that `div` should close, so that only one `div` with `class="box"` is showing at a time.

I initially tried using `slideToggle()` in place of `toggleClass()`but just ended up with the hidden div expanding and contracting four times and then staying 'shut', I assume that's due to the effect being inside the `.each()` loop.

All this code lives inside an `.each()` loop in my `Ajax` function for success.

[A link to my code pen](http://codepen.io/DDD37/pen/GozGGx)

Comment: the clicked div should stay opened, and the rest should close ? funny, it shows and hides 4 times !

Comment: did you try just removing 'false' from the toggleClass() call. that's forcing it to only work in one direction...which would explain why the first toggle request works, and the second one doesn't (because it trying to toggle it to the state it's _already_ in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's happening is that you're adding a click handler to the document targeting the `.forcast-list` n times (n = number of times the `$.each` loops). So when you click on `.forcast-list` it runs the toggle n times. In this case 8 times.

There's 2 ways to fix this:

1. Simply move the click handler outside the `$.each` loop.

[Modified code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJXGbY)

2. Modify your click handler inside the $.each to attach to `.forcast-list` directly

   ```
   $('.forcast-list').on('click', function() {...});
   ```

Comment: I moved the click handler outside the `$.each()` loop and the `.slideToggle()` works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking a couple things may be going on here.

If false is always passed as the second argument to toggleClass() then "hide" will never be added back to the box div.  I would drop the second parameter altogether.

Also, the next() function I think will only try to do the toggle on the box div immediately following forecast-list that is being clicked.

What if you did something like:

```js
$('.box').addClass('hide'); 
$(this).next($('.box')).removeClass('hide');
```

I am thinking this will hide all the boxes and then show the proper one.